# Отправка письма Laravel

Tags: laravel

Сделал на сайте авторизацию, регистрацию и восстановления пароля. Но... когда отправляю письмо на почту, то приходит стандартное письмо. Так вот... Как изменить дизайн этого письма?

Ввел команду, тут что выбрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

С помощью этой команды у вас появится папка `views.emails` с дефолтными шаблонами, которые вы сможете править.

Comment: Изменил вопрос.. ввел команду, выбирать пункт 6?

Comment: попробуйте или 2 или 6, точно не помню честно