# Где в Laravel 5.7 содержится форма отправляемого письма на почту?

Tags: laravel

Тестирую встроенную в laravel 5.7 `Email Verification` и никак не могу найти где содержится форма отправляемого письма на почту. В офф документации информации тоже нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправка письма Laravel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811452/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл, видимо разработчики решили не выносить во `view`

Путь: `/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php`